# Add touch events to elements inside an SVG using SkiaSharp

Tags: svg, xamarin.forms, touch, skiasharp

The Xamarin Forms App is loading the SVG file with a **2D floor plan** and now I need to "select" a particular room and highlight it. I was thinking to add "ClickEvents" to the elements inside of the SVG.

Is there any method to do it? I tried **TapGestureRecognizer** but this applies to the whole SVG instead of a room I tapped.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Yes, please see me anwser

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using **HybridWebView** component with a JavaScript Library to handle the TouchEvents (Select, Zoom, Pan, etc). The details from the selected element can then be sent to the **View** (code behind) via **InvokeAction**

Comment: More details here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

Comment: thanks for the answer but I did not want to implement webview.